# can't get file_exists to work

Tags: php, file-exists

I'm trying to do something that seems simple: If a user would like to change a picture, they can, and if there is no picture, they can upload one.  I want to determine first whether a photo already exists.  If it does, it's filename is site_id.jpg. The variable $site_id connects the correct photo with the correct user.  Here is my code:

```
<?php
$image_exists="";
$image_exists=file_exists('/home/tippc0/public_html/observations_images/160/'.$site_id.'.jpg');

if ($image_exists) {
    echo $image_exists;
    echo $site_id;
?>
<img src="/home/tippc0/public_html/observations_images/160/'.$site_id.'.jpg" />
```

The echo statements are there for troubleshooting, and the `<img src>` is there to show me the photo, again just for troubleshooting.

So, HERE'S THE PROBLEM: "file_exists" says a file exists (returns 1) even through none exists.  I know none exists because (a) there is no file in the database, and (b) I get the standard "no image file exits" icon (the square with the question mark in it) in place of the photo.

If I make up a name for the file instead of of using `'.site_id'.jpg`, it returns false as it should.  If there is no filename and just the path ending in `/160/`, `file_exists` returns true, presumably because the directory "160" exists.

Why is `file_exists` saying a file exists when it doesn't?????

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php - but preferably validate $site_id beforehand

Comment: And the image's output html should be `<img src="/home/tippc0/public_html/observations_images/160/<?php echo $site_id;?>.jpg" />`

Comment: Thank you Mr. Escobar. Your answer is incorporated into Ethan22's answer below, and it helped.  Another question: why should the `<img src>` statement include the `<?php echo ...>` statement, but not the reference to the file in line 3 (`$image_exists=file_exists(...)` )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server will not be able to access the /home/tippc0 directory. It will navigate from the web server root which may be the public_html folder so it's looking for the file here

`/home/tippc0/public_html/observations_images/160/`

but trying to output the file from

`/home/tippc0/public_html/home/tippc0/public_html/observations_images/160/`

which it can't find so your image is broken when it tries to display it. To fix this, make sure the file is stores in a place that can be accessed from the web server. If public_html is your web server root, make your img tag like this:

`<img src="/observations_images/160/<?php echo $site_id; ?>.jpg" />`

Comment: Thank you.  This helped. It allowed me to see that there is in fact an image file, even though other code I have doesn't see it.  I'll have to work on that other code (which I haven't referenced here and is not part of this post).